# Application Crash while using UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

on the first screen user enters data & displaying it in second ViewController using prepareforsegue method.on the second screen user selects multiple rows for delete then again user selects remaining rows for delete application crash.Here is my code

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:]: index 5 in index set beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return mAryValue.count;
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * strIdent=@"id1Cell";

    UITableViewCell * cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strIdent];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strIdent];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[mAryValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.editing)
    {
        return;
    }

    [_tblView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[_tblView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [mArySel addObject:indexPath];
    }
    else if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [mArySel removeObjectIdenticalTo:indexPath];
    }  
}

-(void)getData:(NSMutableArray *)userValues
{
    mAryValue=userValues;
}

- (IBAction)btnDelete:(id)sender
{
        if (mAryValue==nil || mAryValue.count==0)
        {

            UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                          message:@"Please Enter Value"
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                 {
                                     [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                 }];
            UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                                     actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                     {
                                         [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                     }];

            [alert addAction:ok];
            [alert addAction:cancel];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    else
    {
        NSMutableIndexSet *indicesToDelete = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
        for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in mArySel)
        {
            [indicesToDelete addIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        if (!(indicesToDelete==nil) || !(indicesToDelete.count==0))
        {
            [mAryValue removeObjectsAtIndexes:indicesToDelete];

        }
        [_tblView reloadData];
    }


}
```

Please suggest me.
Thank you.

Comment: show the crash report

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:]: index 5 in index set beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'

Comment: check once this line in your code `[mAryValue removeObjectsAtIndexes:indicesToDelete];` , the tableview data source try to access the 5/4 index.

Comment: Thank you for help.its working..

Comment: welcome have a happy day

Answer (score 1):

> [NSMutableArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:]: index 5 in index set beyond
>   bounds [0 .. 4]'

You are trying to remove an object at an index on your `array` that does not exist. As the error says, you are removing `objectAtIndex:5`, but your array only has 4 items.

```
[mAryValue removeObjectsAtIndexes:indicesToDelete];
```

Comment: @AhmedSahib He should get the correct index to start with, not run magic numbers as you suggest.